# Testing a camel route that calls an http server

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

In my camel context I have a route defined as follows:

```
 from("direct:getPets")
           .routeId("getPets")
          .to("http://localhost:4321/pets")
```

The route works well and makes a call to the server. I'd like to test this route and check the headers but I have issues.

This is a spring project so my test class looks as follows:

```
@RunWith(CamelSpringBootRunner.class)
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.After_EACH_TEST_METHO)

@UseAdviceWith
public class TestRestEndpoint {

  @Autowired
  private CamelContext camelContext;

  @Produce(uri = "direct:getPets")
  private ProducerTemplate callServer;

  @EndpointInject(uri = "mock:catchTestEndpoint")


  @Test
  public void should_return_json() throws Exception {
  
   camelContext.getRouteDefinitions("getPets").adviceWith(camelContext, new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {
        @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
       weaveAddLast().to("mock:catchTestEndpoint");
        }
          });

    camelContext.start();

    callServer.sendBody("");
    mockEndpoint.expectedMessageCount(1);
    mockEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied();

}

}
```

The exchange fails and returns a null pointer.

```
org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during execution on the exchange: Exchange[ID-PVJ-DEV97-03-2-1600178584697-0-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your appended Mock is `null`.

If the code in your question really is your code, this is probably because you have a typo in your endpoint URI.

Notice the extra `t` between "catch" and "Test" in `mock:catchtTestEndpoint`

Comment: Oups. That's a typo